# "when" condition is not working in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook where I define a local variable and I want to execute a statement when this local variable is equal with the system variable. For example:

```
vars:
  dev_env: DEV
....
TASK
- name:
  win_copy:
   ...
  when: {{ system_variable}} == dev_env
```

However I always get an error even if I enclose the dev_env into {{}}, if I use "", etc.
I have tried all potential combinations. Do you have a working example so that I could use it as a template?

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to execute a statement when this local variable is equal with the system variable.*

According Ansible documentation [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)

```yaml
  when: system_variable == dev_env
```

**Further Documentation**

- [When should I use `{{ }}`?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)